# Google Sheets casting cell value from Object to Number

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript, google-sheets-custom-function

One cell in a Google Sheets document holds a value given by a SUM of cells formatted as "elapsed hours":"elapsed minutes". Attempting to make calculations in a custom script on this cell will throw errors. Further investigation using typeof() function will show this as "object". How can I convert the cell value to number? Attempted parseInt() or parseFloat() unsuccessfully....
In the linked sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbeoKhiJ3jqYXqfIgAK_tHXPZ_Z1Xrm33ulu9gomXuE/edit#gid=0) you will see that:

- cell A1 having a formula that returns `288:00` formatted as duration,
- cell A2, having `=daysHrsMins(A1)`, that returns a negative value, `-3.179.700.519.840.000,00` from the following function:

  ```
  function daysHrsMins(input) {
     return input*1440;
  }
  ```

Regional settings: Italy
Timezone settings: (GMT +1) Paris

Comment: Add a minimum, complete and verifiable example (add the minimum code necessary to reproduce the problem) and include the textual error messages that you get.

Comment: See here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FbeoKhiJ3jqYXqfIgAK_tHXPZ_Z1Xrm33ulu9gomXuE/edit?usp=sharing - A2 will return type object and calcs are scrambled

Comment: While a link to spreadsheet is helpful, questions should be self contained. Please [edit] the question to add the relevant information.

Comment: Looks that the custom function is working fine. What are the errors that you get?

Comment: Why do I get a negative value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

> How can I convert a cell value to a number?

On Google Sheets durations are just a display format for date values, so when a custom function takes a duration it's treated as a date object.

## Explanation

### Doing arithmetic operations

When we are doing arithmetic operations on dates/times/duration, we should bear in mind the following:

- Google Sheets

  - Use day as the unit
  - Use December 30, 1899 0:00:00 as the zero.
  - Doesn't handle timezones, but spreadsheets has a timezone setting.
- Google Apps Script / JavaScript

  - Use milliseconds as the unit
  - January 1, 1970 0:00:00 in UTC as the zero.
  - Date object includes timezone.
  - The Script project has a timezone setting.

### Display format

- Google Sheets

  - Has a duration format (`[h]:mm:ss.00`).
- Google Apps Script / JavaScript

  - Has the [Utilities Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/) and formatdate method.
  - Hasn't a built-in duration format.

### Transfer of dates between Google Sheets and Google Apps Script

When a date value is transferred from Google Sheets to Google Apps Script or vice versa it is automatically converted considering the timezone of the spreadsheet.

## Solution

As Google Sheets and Google Apps Scripts duration/date handling is different the simplest solution is to do the conversion from date/duration to number on the origin application.

On Google Sheets we could use [TO_PURE_NUMBER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094243?hl=en) to do this conversion:

```
=daysHrsMins(TO_PURE_NUMBER(A1))
```

For certain use cases it could be convenient to use a JavaScript library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

## References

Related Q&A from this site:

- [Formatting Duration values](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/70509/88163)
- [How do I use a negative DURATION formatted cell from Google Spreadsheets in Google Scripts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/80547/88163)
- [How do I calculate a time delta in my Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/22657/88163)

Related Q&A from Stack Overflow

- [How can I do time/hours arithmetic in Google Spreadsheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8890014/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Ruben, I thought that the format is just applied when displaying values, without altering the cell/variable type. Is there a way to pull an "object" and convert it accordingly?

Comment: I have attempted to access the cell using getHours() function, but the result is wrong. Changed the function as follows `function myHours(input) {
  return input.getHours();
  
}`

Comment: @Riccardo: I updated my answer.

Comment: I have changed the function to `function daysHrsMins(input) {
  return TO_PURE_NUMBER(input);`
  
} and now I get an error: `"Error
ReferenceError: "TO_PURE_NUMBER" is not defined. (line 2)."`

Comment: @Riccardo spreadsheet built-in functions doesn't work in Google-apps-script

Comment: Thanks! Any trick to use an equivalent function such as TO_PURE_NUMBER? Of course I could use a temporary cell for this, but there could be a smarter way?

Comment: @Riccardo The "trick" is already in the answer: `=daysHrsMins(TO_PURE_NUMBER(A1))`

Comment: Fantastic help!